# three.js buffer is already interleaved

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have geometries created on my server which have vertices and normals interleaved in one array.   I tried colors also since it is easier to debug.  The ONLY example I can find is webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved_dynamic.html.

Here is what I tried based on the example.  That example is a bit different since it also uses InstancedBufferGeometry but this is based on my understanding of that example:

```
            function exp_crate() {
            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

            // per mesh data x,y,z,r,g,b for 6-element stride 
            var vertexBuffer = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(new Float32Array([
                // Front 
                -1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 1, 0, 
                -1000, -1000, 1000, 1, 0, 1, 
                1000, -1000, 1000, 0, 1, 1, 
                // Back 
                1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1,
                -1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1,
                1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1,
                -1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                // Left 
                -1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                -1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                -1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                -1000, -1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                // Right 
                1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1,
                1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                1000, -1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1,
                // Top 
                -1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1,
                1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1,
                -1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                // Bottom 
                1000, -1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                -1000, -1000, 1000, 0, 0, 1,
                1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
                -1000, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, 1, 
            ]), 6);

            // Use vertexBuffer, starting at offset 0, 3 items in position attribute 
            var positions = new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(vertexBuffer, 3, 0);
            geometry.addAttribute('inVertex', positions);
            // Use vertexBuffer, starting at offset 4, 3 items in color attribute 
            var colors = new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(vertexBuffer, 3, 4);
            geometry.addAttribute('inColor', colors);

            var indices = new Uint16Array([
                0, 1, 2,
                2, 1, 3,
                4, 5, 6,
                6, 5, 7,
                8, 9, 10,
                10, 9, 11,
                12, 13, 14,
                14, 13, 15,
                16, 17, 18,
                18, 17, 19,
                20, 21, 22,
                22, 21, 23
            ]);

            geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));


            docvShader = document.getElementById('cratevertexShader').textContent;
            docfShader = document.getElementById('cratefragmentShader').textContent;

            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: [],
                vertexShader: docvShader,
                fragmentShader: docfShader
            });
            material.side= THREE.DoubleSide;
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);
        }
```

Here are the shaders:

```
        <script id="cratevertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute     highp      vec3   inVertex;
        attribute     highp      vec3   inColor;
        varying       mediump    vec4   Color;                    

        void main()
        { 
          float df; 
          float opac; 

          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(inVertex, 1.0); 
          Color =  vec4(inColor, 1.0); 
        } 
    </script>

    <script id="cratefragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying   mediump   vec4    Color;
        void main() 
        { 
          gl_FragColor = Color; 
          gl_FragColor.w = Color.w; 
        } 
    </script>
```

If I comment out this line:

```
        geometry.addAttribute('inColor', colors);
```

I see a black cube.   If I leave that line in I get the following GL error:

```
    GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

And nothing is displayed at all.  Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offset for the 2nd attribute is not correct.

```
// Use vertexBuffer, starting at offset 0, 3 items in position attribute 
var positions = new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute( vertexBuffer, 3, 0 );
geometry.addAttribute( 'inVertex', positions );

// Use vertexBuffer, starting at offset 3, 3 items in color attribute 
var colors = new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute( vertexBuffer, 3, 3 );
geometry.addAttribute( 'inColor', colors );
```

three.js r.85

Comment: Thanks its always the simple things like counting to three.

Comment: @MichaelIV Yes.